# Выборка двух максимумов из двух разных месяцев MySql

Tags: mysql

Помогите доделать запрос.
Есть два отдельно работающих запроса:

Максимальное число за прошлый месяц:

```
SELECT `maindata`
FROM `counterdata`
WHERE 
`idapart`=1 AND `idcounterosbb`=4
AND `datarec` > LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 2 MONTH 
AND `datarec` < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY `maindata` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

И максимальное число за текущий месяц

```
SELECT a.`maindata`
FROM `counterdata` a
WHERE 
a.`idapart`=1 AND a.`idcounterosbb`=4
AND a.`datarec` > LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
AND a.`datarec` < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 0 MONTH, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY a.`maindata` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

А как их объединить в одном запросе и получить разницу?
Через UNION просто получаем два числа, а желательно поставить их в одну строку, и вычислить разницу.

Вот так попробовал:

```
SELECT a.`maindata` as maxdata, b.`maindata` as mindata
FROM `counterdata` a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT `maindata`
    FROM `counterdata`
    WHERE 
    `idapart`=1 AND `idcounterosbb`=4
    AND `datarec` > LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 2 MONTH 
    AND `datarec` < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    ORDER BY `maindata` DESC
    LIMIT 1 
) b ON NULL
WHERE 
a.`idapart`=1 AND a.`idcounterosbb`=4
AND a.`datarec` > LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
AND a.`datarec` < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 0 MONTH, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY a.`maindata` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Но не могу понять что правильно записать в строчку после ON при объединении.

Answer (score -1):

Решение:

```
SELECT a.`maindata` as maxdata, b.`maindata` as mindata, a.`maindata`-b.`maindata` as delta
    FROM `counterdata` a
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT `maindata`
        FROM `counterdata`
        WHERE 
        `idapart`=1 AND `idcounterosbb`=4
        AND `datarec` > LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 2 MONTH 
        AND `datarec` < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        ORDER BY `maindata` DESC
        LIMIT 1 
    ) b
    WHERE 
    a.`idapart`=1 AND a.`idcounterosbb`=4
    AND a.`datarec` > LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
    AND a.`datarec` < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 0 MONTH, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    ORDER BY a.`maindata` DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Запрос неверный. Например, вот в этом месте: ```AND `datarec` < DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, INTERVAL 1 DAY)```

Comment: Запрос работает (проверен раз 20). Не правильный с точки зрения лексики языка?

Comment: Дерьмово проверен. Выражение теоретически должно посчитать что? первый день какого-то месяца, верно? ну так проверь, что ты получишь, если, скажем, текущая дата 5-е февраля...

Comment: спасибо. понял ошибку.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=790c2e7243b45f6f1cb042d0975f81c4